# How to change rails model object variable names that holds object of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have this model and associated schema defined.

```
class Memory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :memory_slot
end

class MemorySlot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memories
end
```

Now typically it let me can access memory slots of Memory via `@memory.memory_slot.name`. But I want to access it via different method like `@memory.supporting_memory_slot.name`. What is the best way I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need any new migration, you can use the previous `memory_slot_id`, and still can change the name like following:

```
class Memory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supporting_memory_slot, class_name: 'MemorySlot', foreign_key: 'memory_slot_id'
end

class MemorySlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memories
end
```

This way, if you had any records saved previously, they will work in the current scenario as well. But if you generate a new migration, the old records saved will not be accessible, because they were used using the `foreign_key` as `memory_slot_id`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change your `model association` like this

```
class Memory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :supporting_memory_slot, :class_name => 'MemorySlot', :foreign_key => 'supporting_memory_slot_id'
end
```

then you can do something like this

```
@memory.supporting_memory_slot.name
```

***Note:*** In this case,you must generate a new `migration` to add `supporting_memory_slot_id` to your `memories` table

Comment: Can he just point foreign key to memory_slot_id, like `foreign_key: memory_slot_id`?

Comment: @caspg No! Rails always look for `(model_name)_id` as **FK**. In this case it is `supporting_memory_slot_id` as the `model_name` is `supporting_memory_slot`

Comment: @Pavan this isn't the case. Rails will look `memory_slot_id` if you say it explicitly. And the mode name as you specify is `class_name: 'MemorySlot'`, not `SupportingMemorySlot`

Comment: @Pavan So you can't say that **You must generate a new ...**. It is up to the developer what he wants. Either he wants to continue with old `foreign_key` which is most suitable, or he wants to continue with the new one as you specified in your answer.

Comment: @ArslanAli It is always recommended to specify a different FK to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @Pavan I agree. But not necessary. What if you have thousands of records already saved in the database, what would you do?

Comment: @Pavan I took it back. But you really can't impose your personal preference on anyone. I'd like to give all the options to a newbie and then, let him decide with what options does he want to go.